# Is V() a utility function in Visual Basic?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to reverse engineer a calculator made with visual basic. The original author has this function called on a lot of variables that looks like:

```
V(Offset)
V(CPX)
V(CAng)
```

I can't find this anywhere in any of the functions that he wrote. But I also don't think this is a utility function in visual basic. Does anyone know what this means?

My best guess is that this is converting the units of the numbers it is called on to a format that is compatible with other numbers.

Comment: `V` is not a part VB6 and I can't name VBA host applications that would have it. To find it, right-click the `V` in the source code and select `Definition`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is not defined. I think I'm going to close this question. I think the original author was using a file that I do not have access to.

Comment: Try searching the project for `v as` or `redim v`. V looks like a variant array.

Comment: I found `ReDim V(LastIO)` in the file. Doesn't that just free LastIO?

Comment: @toshiomagic No, that resizes `V` to be an array of `LastIO + 1` elements (or `LastIO` elements if `Option Base 1` is used).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by GSerg above, V is not a utility function.